# Is it possible to have a domain point to a plex media server?

Tags: wireless, web-server, media-server

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge of the raspberry pi and stuff in advance. But anyways I was wondering if there is any way for me to get a domain and when that domain is visited you are prompted with a login page and if you have an account(accounts would be for family only) you can stream movies off the Plex media server. If possible it would be awesome if it could all be done on one raspberry pi. Thank you guys in advance I am completely open to suggestions.

Edit: I have port forwarded the 32400 port and I enabled remote access on plex and it says I can access it outside of my network but I would like it to be the way stated above ^^ . I am aware I can invite people to share my library but I would like to just have people visit and stream my library. When I go to my private ip (ex. 192.xxx.x.xx:32400/web) is what i would like it to be like Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Port forward the needed ports (do some research on this)
2. Go to your domain registrar/DNS provider. Set the A record of your domain to your public IP address.

   - You can check by opening `icanhazip.com` on your Pi
   - You can check via the command line using the command `curl icanhazip.com`
3. Visit `[mydomain.com]:32400/web`

   - You can also port forward 32400 to port 80 depending on your router. In that case, simply open `[mydomain.com]/web`

Comment: I have a domain with namecheap and while i am trying to create the A record to my public ip I get this error:  "Error occurred while processing the command with the service provider."  It is my public ip and my host is '@' and the TTL is automatic if that makes a difference. Thank you for the help

Comment: @connormarchand screenshot?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ifMzK     I put in my public ip and it doesnt work and I also tried my private ip. When i google what my ip is a different one than the ip that my raspberry pi is connected to btw.

Comment: @connormarchand Looks okay. I think that's namecheap's problem, or your public IP isn't really public. In that case, contact your ISP.

Comment: When I go into plex and look at the server settings it has my private ip with a green arrow to my public ip with a green arrow to the internet. It says that I can use my server anywhere because with remote access

Comment: @connormarchand Did you already set your domain's A record to your public IP? It will take some time for the changes to propagate.

Comment: Yes I set it but when I go to the domain it says that the DNS server cant be found

Comment: @connormarchand I can access your site from my end.

Comment: @connormarchand `http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com:32400/web`

Comment: Dang well i cant access it. It still says that the DNS is not there

Comment: @connormarchand Try setting your computer's DNS server to one of the more reliable ones like OpenDNS' `208.67.222.222` or Google's `8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to work with a dynamic DNS service. You'll need to have your router forward the port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) of your public address on your router to port 32400 of your Raspberry. There's a manual that came with your router that will tell you how to do that. Other than that, you'll just need to regularly update your current IP address with the Dynamic DNS service and you'll be all set.

Alternatively, you can also forward port 32400 of your public address to port 32400 of your Raspberry. That will "hide" the service a little from crawlers like Google and Bing.